# Split a string (url) in multiple pieces by different patterns in php

Tags: php, arrays, explode

I have the following string

```
$searchlink = 'search-all.php?page=1&MakeId=BMW&BodyId=Coupe&ModelId=320&PriceToId=%C2%A3+20000&PriceFromId=%C2%A3+100&FuelId=Diesel&MilageId=%26gt%3B5000+miles+&DistanceId=%26gt%3B10+miles&AgeId=%26gt%3B1+years&postcodeId=&keywordId=&TransmissionId=Automatic&Search=Finddata';
```

and I tried with explode to split it by the =:

```
$searchlink = explode('=', $searchlink);
```

and the var_dump for this resulted

```
array(15) { 
  [0]=> string(19) "search-all.php?page" 
  [1]=> string(8) "1&MakeId" 
  [2]=> string(10) "BMW&BodyId" 
  [3]=> string(13) "Coupe&ModelId" 
  [4]=> string(13) "320&PriceToId" 
  [5]=> string(24) "%C2%A3+20000&PriceFromId" 
  [6]=> string(17) "%C2%A3+100&FuelId" 
  [7]=> string(15) "Diesel&MilageId" 
  [8]=> string(30) "%26gt%3B5000+miles+&DistanceId" 
  [9]=> string(22) "%26gt%3B10+miles&AgeId" 
 [10]=> string(26) "%26gt%3B1+years&postcodeId" 
 [11]=> string(10) "&keywordId" 
 [12]=> string(15) "&TransmissionId" 
 [13]=> string(16) "Automatic&Search" 
 [14]=> string(8) "Finddata"
```

So I tried doing another explode based on `&` after the explode i have done, but resulted in a `NULL`. Tried smth like `$searchlink = explode('&', $searchlink)`.

My final code was:

```
<?php
$searchlink = 'search-all.php?page=1&MakeId=BMW&BodyId=Coupe&ModelId=320&PriceToId=%C2%A3+20000&PriceFromId=%C2%A3+100&FuelId=Diesel&MilageId=%26gt%3B5000+miles+&DistanceId=%26gt%3B10+miles&AgeId=%26gt%3B1+years&postcodeId=&keywordId=&TransmissionId=Automatic&Search=Finddata';
$searchlink = explode('=', $searchlink);
$searchlink = explode('&', $searchlink);
?>
```

The expected output would be 
`BMW 320 Coupe PricefromId 100 PricetoId 20000 FuelId Diesel MilageId 5000 DistanceId 10 AgeId 1 PostocodeId KeywordId TransmissionId Automatic.`

Please help me on this I ran out of ideas. Your help will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Discover [`parse_str()`](http://php.net/parse_str)

```
$searchlink = 'search-all.php?page=1&MakeId=BMW&BodyId=Coupe&ModelId=320&PriceToId=%C2%A3+20000&PriceFromId=%C2%A3+100&FuelId=Diesel&MilageId=%26gt%3B5000+miles+&DistanceId=%26gt%3B10+miles&AgeId=%26gt%3B1+years&postcodeId=&keywordId=&TransmissionId=Automatic&Search=Finddata';
parse_str($searchlink, $result);
//var_dump($result);
```

Comment: hmm, so I add before the explode the parse_str?

Comment: You get rid of `explode()` and result in array with key-values via only one function

Comment: Thank you so much, will accept the answer in a few mins. I really searched for this, but it also matter how you search.